# Table creation fails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, h2

I'm using an H2 database for testing my Grails app. I have some simple domain classes like:

```
package mypackage

class UserSession {
    User user
    String sessionTokenHash

    // last seen info
    String lastSeenIP
    Date lastSeenTime
    String lastSeenUserAgent
    String lastSeenURL
}
```

however, the table doesn't seem to get created correctly.

```
hbm2ddl.SchemaExport Unsuccessful: create table user_session (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not null, last_seenip varchar(255) not null, last_seen_time datetime not null, last_seenurl varchar(255) not null, last_seen_user_agent varchar(255) not null, session_token_hash varchar(255) not null, user_id bigint not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB
hbm2ddl.SchemaExport Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE USER_SESSION (ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL, LAST_SEENIP VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, LAST_SEEN_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL, LAST_SEENURL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, LAST_SEEN_USER_AGENT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, SESSION_TOKEN_HASH VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, USER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID)) ENGINE=[*]INNODB "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
create table user_session (id bigint not null auto_increment, version bigint not null, last_seenip varchar(255) not null, last_seen_time datetime not null, last_seenurl varchar(255) not null, last_seen_user_agent varchar(255) not null, session_token_hash varchar(255) not null, user_id bigint not null, primary key (id)) ENGINE=InnoDB [42001-147]
```

It's set to use a temporary in-memory H2 database in `create-drop` mode.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but I try to stay away from "common" words like "User" and "Session" in my domain names because they could have some kind of protected grails behavior or even possibly some reserved use in H2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was using the wrong dialect; my DataSource.groovy had the following dialect set in the dataSource block:

```
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
```

I added the following line for the development data source:

```
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"
```

This has fixed the problem.